# Code Igniter - how to redirect user after login?

Tags: php, session, codeigniter, redirect

I've a Code Igniter project using database backed sessions. The web application is password protected, meaning that I have an abstract controller checking if the user is logged in before I allow him to see any pages, apart from the login form.

While I had no problems implementing this, I'm having some difficulty understanding how to make the application redirect the user to the page he wanted to see if he need to login first.

How it goes: the user is logged out and types in a URL. The application detects he's not logged in so send him to the login page and creates a row in the ci_session table. At the same time I store the url the user entered in the session object using either flashdata or userdata. My problem is that once the user logs in, the application will create a new row in the database, meaning a new session, completely ignoring the values I stored previously.

Shouldn't it be one row per session?

Comment: Hmm. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2130361) seems to suggest things should work as you're expecting, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

My problem was not how to redirect or how to store data. My problem was the application creating two sessions per request.

I changed the name of my cookie to something that didn't include underscores and voila, fixed. One session per request and everything works as it should.

Answer (score 2):

The CI URL Helper has a redirect function that you can use. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

> Does a "header redirect" to the local URI specified. Just like other functions in this helper, this one is designed to redirect to a local URL within your site. You will not specify the full site URL, but rather simply the URI segments to the controller you want to direct to. The function will build the URL based on your config file values.
>
> The optional second parameter allows you to choose between the "location" method (default) or the "refresh" method. Location is faster, but on Windows servers it can sometimes be a problem. The optional third parameter allows you to send a specific HTTP Response Code - this could be used for example to create 301 redirects for search engine purposes. The default Response Code is 302. The third parameter is only available with 'location' redirects, and not 'refresh'. Examples:

```
if ($logged_in == FALSE)
{
     redirect('/login/form/', 'refresh');
}

// with 301 redirect
redirect('/article/13', 'location', 301);
```

Comment: My problem is not redirecting - I can do that easily. My problem is storing and retrieving the URL the user tried to go to on the session.

Comment: Take a look at the answer Matt pointed you to in the comment below your question.  You can store the redirect URL in the session.

Comment: I'm trying, but the session class creates two rows in the database, one for the request done when I'm logged out and one when I login. When I try to fetch the URL from the session it comes out empty.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're misunderstanding how sessions works between a browser and your web application. When a user opens your login page, they are assigned a unique session ID which codeigniter keeps track of. Unless your session gets expired, either forcefully by logging out or due to your own session expire settings, codeigniter should only be writing 1 row per unique session in your database. Make sure you have your sess_expiration variable in config.php set to something realistic.

I don't see how removing the underscore from your cookie name could have fixed this, as the name has nothing to do with how sessions work in general.

Comment: I don't either, but it did. The only bit of code I changed to make this work was removing the underscore from the cookie name.

Answer (score 0):

You can user something like this.

When the user tries to access a page like

```
http://test.com/userpage.php
```

If he is not logged in, redirect him to

```
http://test.com/login.php?redirectpage=userpage.php
```

(This redirect will be done by userpage.php after checking the login status from the cookie or the session.)

The login page has the value "redirectpage" and once the user logs in at the login page, redirect him to the page he was previously trying to visit.

You will have to check the user login status in all the pages that you need the user to be logged in.